# Programmatically log into a website

Tags: post, curl, terminal, http-post

I am trying to write a quick application to view my electric bills programatically. For that I need to be able to log into the website programmatically before I can move ahead with anything else.

I know that one has to use curl in some way for that. But, I am not sure how I can leverage curl to log into the website through terminal. Here is the website: [Seattle Utilitiy Bills Website](https://secure4.billerweb.com/csg/inetSrv)

Looking at the corresponding source for the login form, it look like this:

```
<tr>
    <td nowrap class="form-style-text">User ID:</td>
    <td class="form-style-label"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" size="17" name="loginid" maxlength="32"></td>
</tr>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.wizForm.loginid.focus()</script>
<tr>
    <td class="form-style-text">Password:</td>
    <td class="form-style-label"><input type="password" autocomplete="off" name="password" size="17" maxlength="16"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="form-style-text">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left">
        <input name="login" type="submit" class="actionbutton" onClick="doLogin()" value="Log in"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I know I need to use curl in some way to be able to log in, but I am not sure how. Specially because the login logic is being done by the `'doLogin()'` function, and I am not sure how I can call that function from the terminal using curl. Here is the definition of the `'doLogin()'` function:

```
function doLogin() {
    var wform = document.wizForm;
    wform.type.value='LoginMenu';
}
```

Any clues how I can log into this page using terminal/curl?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the form tag. `<form class="extform" action="/csg/inetSrv" method="post" name="wizForm">`

Most likely you need to save a session cookie after you logged in.

What you need to do is use curl to post the form-data to /csg/inetSrv. use the parameter `--cookie-jar <file>` to save the cookie. Then you can use curl again to make requests with the cookie file and you are logged in.

It might be easier to check the cookie in a browser first to understand how it is used. You can then try using curl with the browsers session cookie to test before you use curl to log in.